# How to stop the job in gitlab-ci.yml when we have failure on previous stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a sonar report, if quality gate passed then it will run for next stage and do deployment, if quality gates failed then stop the gitlab job. but in the job stages we have a rollback it will run when we have failure so in this case if sonar failed that rollback is executed. I want to stop the rollback execution. It should run only when we have deployment failure job stage which is basically next stage of sonar.

```
image: maven-jdk-8
cache:
  paths:
    - ./.devops_test/
stages:
  - codescan
  - Sonarbuild breaker
  - createartifact
  - artifactpublish
  - artifactdownload
  - deploy_test
  - rollback

code_scan:
  stage: codescan
  image: sdldevelopers/sonar-scanner
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - cd ./.devops_test
    - java -jar SourceCode_Extract_V3.jar ../07-METADATA/metadata/ javascript_extracts/
    - chmod 777 ../02-SHELL/stage-codescan.sh
    - cd ..
    - ./02-SHELL/stage-codescan.sh
  allow_failure: false


Sonar Build Breaker:
  stage: Sonarbuild breaker
  tags:
    - test-shell-runner
  script:
    - chmod 777 /xxx/quality_gate_status_Check.sh
    - /xxx/quality_gate_status_Check.sh
  allow_failure: false



archive_metadata:
     stage: createartifact
     tags:
       - tag-docker-grp
     script:
       - zip ./.devops/lib/metadata.zip -r ./07-METADATA/
     only:
      - test-pipeline_test
     when: on_success


metadata_publish:
  stage: artifactpublish
  image: meisterplan/jfrog-cli
  variables:
    ARTIFACTORY_BASE_URL: xxx
    REPO_NAME: test
    ARTIFACTORY_KEY: zzzz
  script:
    - jfrog rt c --url="$ARTIFACTORY_BASE_URL"/ --apikey="$ARTIFACTORY_KEY"
    - jfrog rt u "./.devops/lib/my_metadata.zip" "$REPO_NAME"/test/test"$CI_PIPELINE_ID".zip --recursive=false
  tags:
    - tag-docker-grp
  only:
    - test-pipeline_test

metadata_download:
     stage: artifactdownload
     variables:
      ARTIFACTORY_BASE_URL: xxxx
      REPO_NAME: dddd
      ARTIFACTORY_KEY: ffff
     script:
      - cd /home/test/newmetadata/
      - wget https://axxxxx"$CI_PIPELINE_ID".zip
      - mv test"$CI_PIPELINE_ID".zip test_metadata.zip
     tags:
      - test-shell-runner
     only:
      - test-pipeline_test

Deploy_code:
     stage: deploy_test
     tags:
      - test-shell-runner
     script:
      - cd ./02-SHELL/
      - pwd
      - echo $CI_PIPELINE_ID > /home/test/newmetadata/build_test.txt
      - echo $CI_PIPELINE_ID > /home/test/newmetadata/postbuild_test.txt
      - ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/hosts deployment.yml -v
     only:
      - test-pipeline_test

rollback_test_deploy:
     stage: rollback
     tags:
      - test-shell-runner
     script:
      - cd /home/test/newmetadata/
      - chmod 777 /home/test/newmetadata/postbuild_test.txt
      - previousbuild=$(cat /home/test/newmetadata/postbuild_test.txt)
      - echo "previous successfull build is $previousbuild"
      - wget xxx"$previousbuild".zip
      - ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/hosts /root/builds/xaaa/rollback_deployment.yml -e "previousbuild=${previousbuild}" -vv
     when: on_failure
```

Comment: rollback will run only when deploy_code fails, not in case of any other stage failure.This is what i want...here if sonar breaker failed then the rollback is running i want to stop that run.

Answer (score 3):

You can mark with a file if codescan succeeded:

```
code_scan:
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - codescan_succeeded
  stage: codescan
  image: sdldevelopers/sonar-scanner
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - cd ./.devops_test
    - java -jar SourceCode_Extract_V3.jar ../07-METADATA/metadata/ javascript_extracts/
    - chmod 777 ../02-SHELL/stage-codescan.sh
    - cd ..
    - ./02-SHELL/stage-codescan.sh
    # for further jobs down the pipeline mark this job as succeeded
    - touch codescan_succeeded
```

If codescan fails, there is no file `codescan_succeeded`. In the rollback job, check if the file exists. If it does not exist, you can abort the rollback job:

```
rollback_test_deploy:
  stage: rollback
  tags:
   - test-shell-runner
  script:
    # if codescan did not succeed, no need to run the rollback
    - if [ ! -f codescan_succeeded ]; then exit 0 fi
    - cd /home/test/newmetadata/
    - chmod 777 /home/test/newmetadata/postbuild_test.txt
    - previousbuild=$(cat /home/test/newmetadata/postbuild_test.txt)
    - echo "previous successfull build is $previousbuild"
    - wget xxx"$previousbuild".zip
    - ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/hosts /root/builds/xaaa/rollback_deployment.yml -e "previousbuild=${previousbuild}" -vv
  when: on_failure
```

You don't need to mark jobs with `allow_failure: false`. That's the default value.

Comment: Thanks @mles. I hope this should work. I will test further.

Comment: is there any mechanism to not run the rollback job? it was running in the above condition as well.

Comment: there is no mechanism to not run the rollback job after the pipeline has started. you can only run the the rollback job, but skip the actions, like I suggested.