# how to execute stages conditionally in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I have a requirement where I need to check the condition of a script executed in stage 1. If the condition is true, then the execution to continue with stage 2 and if the condition is false, it should stop and exit at stage 1 itself without going to the next stage. Also, I don't want to show the stage 1 as failed if the condition is false.

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: possibly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126000/how-to-stop-the-job-in-gitlab-ci-yml-when-we-have-failure-on-previous-stage?rq=1